Saving Wordpress post without reloading page (admin side)
I know how to save a custom field value to the database using ajax.
However have a particular post type with a lot of fields inside nested groups, repeaters etc.
While I could adapt the JS function to take into account all situations so as all fields values are saved, it seems a little too risky.
Is there a way to trigger the WP default save_post function without reloading the post?
